# when my url has ? mark event.preventDefault() or return false don't work on form submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying event.preventDefault() or return false.
None of them working when I have ? at the end of my url.
My url is http://127.0.0.1:789/

but, whenever I hit enter of click on button. It will refresh the page and url becomes
http://127.0.0.1:789/?
and no matter what I do it will continue to refresh the page. I check all the questions.
I was trying to make a chat application. Which is on node
If it refreshes i get problems

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Chat application Using Node</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * { margin: 0 , auto; padding:  0; box-sizing: border-box;}
    body { font: 15px helvetica, arial;}
    form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
    form input{ border:0; padding: 10px; width: 85%; margin-right: .5%;}
    form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130 ,224, 255); border: none; padding:10px; }

    #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    #messages li { padding: 5px 10px;}
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) {background: #eee;}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        $("form").on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="messages">
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off">
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried everything nothing works unless i manually put # at the end of url.

Comment: use dom ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your script in the document ready function (it is currently executed before the DOM is finished loading.)

```
$(function() {
   $("form").on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
   });
});
```

The question mark is because the form sends a GET request to the current page.